# Unserialize PHP session data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.x with database session driver and i want to access `data` cloumn that `BLOB` type. Here my blob data:

```
__ci_last_regenerate|i:1435420891;identity|s:13:"john@doe.com ";username|s:13:"johndoe";email|s:13:"john@doe.com ";user_id|s:1:"5";old_last_login|s:10:"1435412865";
```

I tried with `unserialize($string)` but didnt work!

> unserialize(): Error at offset 0

How can i access blob data element? For ex: `$user['email']`

Comment: Are you storing 'BLOB' data in your session? It is an interesting approach. Are you are aware that 'session data' is automatically serialized when the PHP script ends and is 'unserialized' when you 'start_session' again. Why are you using `unserialize($string)` on 'session data'? Unless you 'serialized' it when you added it to the session?

Comment: @RyanVincent Not me! This data is session and stored by CodeIgniter. I tried to access BLOB data elements but i couldnt get. When i echo `blob` data, i get above string looks like serialized data but `unserialize` not working. What type of this string?

Comment: @RyanVincent I have to tell you all CodeIgniter core and session library :)

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's no straight-forward way to do that ... You could use [session_decode()](http://php.net/session_decode), but it requires that you already have an active session, so that it can put the decoded data into `$_SESSION`.

I must tell you however, if you want to do that - you're doing it wrong. You should never access another user's session. If there's some data that's tied to a session that's not explicit to the user who owns the session, you should just add another field to the sessions table and save it in there.

Comment: The sessions are serialized using PHP's internal serialization function `php_serialize`, so by unserializing with this method, one is able to get the data back without writing to `$_SESSION`. See `unserialize_php` here: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.session-decode.php#108037

Comment: That is a user-provided function and is *not* binary-safe.

Comment: Still better than adding another user's session data to one's own... It will work for most cases though.

Comment: Neither is better, which is why my answer says that the idea is wrong in the first place.

Comment: Who are we to judge? The OP wanted to do it, let him do it is my answer.

Comment: The fact that this is a hard thing to do is not a coincidence ... it's not a matter of you and me judging. If the OP wants to do something, but doesn't know how, then they also don't understand the implications that come with it.

Comment: Okay, I get your point of view. Now could you motivate why "You should never access another user's session"? and why "you should just add another field to the sessions table", since it seems to be evil and the OP doesn't know why.

Comment: That's like asking me to explain why you'd want to have separate name, email, password, etc. fields in a `users` database table instead of serializing the contents and storing them in a text field ... Sorry, but I'm not doing it here and now; we've made this comment section too chatty already - I'm out.

Comment: I'll end this discussion by saying that the OP uses a framework with set internal mechanics for session storage, as he already explained. Adding columns in the table would require an extension of core libraries of said framework which is usually not advised. and in this case quite complicated.

Comment: I said I'm out, but since you mentioned the framework mechanics ... I wrote `CI_Session` and I can assure you that adding an extra column to the sessions table is not at all complicated, as it was planned for (on top of CodeIgniter being easily extendable in the first place). Most applications need only update the said column on login, and override `CI_Session::sess_regenerate()` to update it again after ID regeneration. Had the OP asked about this, I would've given some tips, but the question is really vague about the intended functionality, so ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution here

So I have used session decode http://php.net/session_decode

```
session_decode('__ci_last_regenerate|i:1446535049;ci_UserID|s:1:"2";ci_UserName|s:24:"example@xyz.com";logged_in|b:1;');
```

So session decode stored all the encrypted data in normal php session.

Which I can access using:

```
echo $_SESSION['ci_UserID'];
```

Comment: By reading the comments in the doc, I found this guy's solution: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.session-decode.php#108037 . He made a standalone version of PHP's internal unserialize function `unserialize_php` which does this without writing to the `$_SESSION` variable (that's messy).

Answer (score 0):

As Narf says there is no easy way to do this.

ykay;s solution presupposes that you are using the current built in session handler. That can be changed at any time by the application, and there are no guarantees that PHP will keep this format.

Your solution trashes the current session and replaces it with the stored data (but at least it will use the "current" serialization method).

The serialization function and the read/write operations for session_ functions can be overridden at runtime. As long as you read back data encoded using the same mechanism as you use for decoding your mechanism will work - but it is a bad approach for long term storage of data or for use in a context where you cannot guarantee consistency of the PHP installations reading the data.

The right way to fix the problem of reading session data outside of a user's session is to use the serialize/unserialize format:

```
ini_set("session.serialize_handler", 'php_serialize');
```

Then use unserialize() to read the data.