# How to unserialize codeigniter session data from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wan to use CI session in a external script and I got following data from database.

```
 __ci_last_regenerate|i:1446535049;ci_UserID|s:1:"2";ci_UserName|s:24:"example@xyz.com";logged_in|b:1;
```

I have tried `unserialize` and `unserialize(base64_decode($data))` but I am fail yet.

Please help to extract this data.

Comment: can you clear bit more about your requirement

Comment: Are you sure that your data is serialized using `base64_encode`?

Comment: I am not sure how codeigniter encode and store in database in binary field. I have extract data field form database and got this output.

Comment: Abdulla, I just want to get ci_UserID value..

Comment: __ci_last_regenerate|i:1446535049;ci_UserID|s:1:"2";ci_UserName|s:24:"example@xyz.com";logged_in|b:1;
Here you can see ci_UserID value is 1 but I am not sure how to get it using php code.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090982/unserialize-php-session-data this is very similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution [here](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61347.html)

So I have used [session decode](http://php.net/session_decode)

```
session_decode('__ci_last_regenerate|i:1446535049;ci_UserID|s:1:"2";ci_UserName|s:24:"example@xyz.com";logged_in|b:1;');
```

So session decode stored all the encrypted data in normal php session.

Which I can access using: `echo $_SESSION['ci_UserID'];`

Well guys thanks for the help

Comment: Usefull if you want to retrieve a session, but if you want to parse data and do something with it (like a foreach sessions) that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a session variable, you can use CodeIgniter's own session library. Consider the following code (in a controller):

```
$this->load->library('session');                // load the session library
$session_data = $this->session->all_userdata(); // get all session data
print_r($session_data);                         // print and get the corrresponding variable name, e.g. "item"
$var = $this->session->userdata('item');        // pick one that suits your needs, e.g. item
```

Sorry, I have read "the external script" only after having posted the code. This obviously only works in the CI framework.

For an external script you may need to have a closer look. The variables are separated by ";" and "|" and then serialized, so this might work (not tested):

```
$row = explode(';', '__ci_last_regenerate|i:1446535049;ci_UserID|s:1:"2";ci_UserName|s:24:"example@xyz.com";logged_in|b:1;'); // load the database row
$userid = explode('|', $row[1]);
$userid = unserialize($userid[1]); // now $userid holds the value "2"
```

Comment: I have integrated a external script where I am trying to get session values directly from database.

Comment: I was trying to get a proper solution.. if you don't mind please have a look at my answer..

Comment: I got this solution from last reply of this thread
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61347.html